# How to use node package made with coffee script

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I've set up an app using express. I'm trying to use a package called node-pocket (https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-pocket). This package is written in coffee script. When I try and run this app I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './node_modules/node-pocket/index.js'
```

I have looked and see that the location only combines index.coffee. I can work around this by creating an index.js file manually, but could someone please explain why this is breaking? I presume there is something I can do so the coffee script gets automatically compiled to .js?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`require('coffee-script/register')`](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/1.7.0/src/register.coffee) and then include the CoffeeScript code, it should get compiled automatically if the extension matches.